How to solidify a mesh object only connected with vertices with multiple curvatures?
How can I make a single object for 3d printing while making sure the vertices on the mesh are connected accordingly? The picture gives the object from 3 different views highlighting the different angles.

Addendum: I can't delete the previous question which is reduced to this single problem because "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."


You don't have to delete the other question. Instead it would have been better to just update and revise your previous post, instead of posting another question. Also as already mentioned in the other question, this is not really usable model, you have to model it properly. I suggest you go through a few tutorials first on how to model stuff in Blender like this tutorial for beginners or this one

hello it's not clear what you mean by "making sure the vertices on the mesh are connected accordingly", could you please elaborate?

@moonboots I think the OP means those jagged edges; he wants them to be smoothly connected. However, that is just addressing the consequence of incorrect modeling techniques.

@moonboots yes Harry is indeed right, modelling technique is indeed off but this is a one time project for me anyway.

So basically just smoothing the surface.

This feels like arguing with a little kid that lighting a whole role of caps will not produce a gigantic explosion, but they want to try it anyway. Alright, since you insist on wasting your time and 3-D printing materials on a part that is not the same shape as the part in the photo, I will help you make it the way you think you want.


Select All [a]
Make sure you are in edge select mode.
Select boundary loop.
Smooth Vertices [Ctrl+V, select option from menu]
Go to the operation properties panel in the bottom left of the 3D Viewport editor, and raise the Smoothing to 1 (the default is 0.5).
Add a Solidify modifier to the object.
Adjust the modifier's Solidify width as desired.
Adjust the modifier's Offset value to 1 or -1 as needed to make sure the mesh is being solidified outward, not inward.

You should now be able to export the mesh.
